# Combining divs?

Tags: css, html, layout

I laid out my table just like I wanted it to look using colspans and rowspans.  However, I was informed that I needed to do the same layout using divs and I'm fairly lost now.  I've searched, but nothing I've tried so far works.  I think the problem I may be having is the fact that the divs I need to merge or combine are in separate containing divs.

Here's the td version:

```
    <link href="CSS/oneColFixCtrHdr.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <table width="74%" height="143" class="OTIFheader">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="52" rowspan="3" align="center">Sourcing Manager</td>
      <td width="46" rowspan="3" align="center">Supplier</td>
      <td colspan="6" align="center">Fixture</td>
      <td colspan="6" align="center">Pre-Con</td>
      <td width="33" rowspan="2" align="center">Distro</td>
      <td width="56" rowspan="2" align="center">Requests E-Fix</td>
      <td width="55" rowspan="2" align="center">Replenish</td>
      <td width="50" rowspan="2" align="center">FM/Parts</td>
      <td width="48" rowspan="2" align="center">Supplies</td>
      <td width="48" rowspan="2" align="center">Systems</td>
      <td width="36" rowspan="2" align="center">Puerto Rico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center">New Store</td>
      <td colspan="2" align="center">Remodel</td>
      <td colspan="2" align="center">Special Proj</td>
      <td colspan="2" align="center">New Store</td>
      <td colspan="2" align="center">Remodel</td>
      <td colspan="2" align="center">Special Proj</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="19" align="center">Int</td>
      <td width="24" align="center">AO</td>
      <td width="22" align="center">Int</td>
      <td width="25" align="center">AO</td>
      <td width="23" align="center">Int</td>
      <td width="28" align="center">AO</td>
      <td width="24" align="center">INT</td>
      <td width="22" align="center">AO</td>
      <td width="27" align="center">INT </td>
      <td width="19" align="center">AO</td>
      <td width="27" align="center">INT</td>
      <td width="24" align="center">AO</td>
      <td align="center">INT</td>
      <td align="center">INT</td>
      <td align="center">INT</td>
      <td align="center">INT</td>
      <td align="center">INT</td>
      <td align="center">INT</td>
      <td align="center">INT</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And here's the div version:

```
<div class="OTIFscrollingTableHeader" style="display:none">
<div class="gridHeader">
    <div class="gridCell" style="width: 10%;"></div>
    <div class="gridCell" style="width: 10%;"></div>
    <div class="gridCell" style="width: 30%;">Fixture</div>
    <div class="gridCell" style="width: 30%;">Pre-Con</div>
    <div class="gridCell" style="width: 5%;">Distro</div>
    <div class="gridCell" style="width: 5%;">Requests E-Fix</div>
    <div class="gridCell" style="width: 5%;">Replenish</div>
    <div class="gridCell" style="width: 5%;">FM/Parts</div>
    <div class="gridCell" style="width: 5%;">Supplies</div>
    <div class="gridCell" style="width: 5%;">Systems</div>
    <div class="gridCell" style="width: 5%;">Puerto Rico</div>
</div>
<div class="gridHeader">
    <div class="gridCell" style="width: 10%;"></div>
    <div class="gridCell" style="width: 10%;"></div>
    <div class="gridCell" style="width: 10%;">New Store</div>
    <div class="gridCell" style="width: 10%;">Remodel</div>
    <div class="gridCell" style="width: 10%;">Special Proj</div>
    <div class="gridCell" style="width: 10%;">New Store</div>
    <div class="gridCell" style="width: 10%;">Remodel</div>
    <div class="gridCell" style="width: 10%;">Special Proj</div>
    <div class="gridCell" style="width: 5%;"></div>
    <div class="gridCell" style="width: 5%;"></div>
    <div class="gridCell" style="width: 5%;"></div>
    <div class="gridCell" style="width: 5%;"></div>
    <div class="gridCell" style="width: 5%;"></div>
    <div class="gridCell" style="width: 5%;"></div>
    <div class="gridCell" style="width: 5%;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can you bootstrap grid system for this purpose here is the all docs for [grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid)

here is this basic example of it. you don't have to write extra css. it's easy and simple.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">.col-md-8</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that!  Bootstrap's pre-defined css is very useful, but it still doesn't solve my "merging divs" issue across rows.